# How to reset recyclerView position item views to original state after refreshing adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` with rows that have views that when clicked will be disabled for that row position.

The problem is after I update the adapter like this:

```
    adapterData.clear();
    adapterData.addAll(refreshedAdapterData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After refreshing the data, the disabled views at the previous recycler position still remain disabled even though the data is refreshed.
How can I reset the views to the original state after refreshing adapter data.

Comment: how exactly are these views model related to the recycler view

Comment: post appropriate code here

Answer (score 6):

Use below code.

```
  adapterData.clear();
adapterData.addAll(refreshedAdapterData);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

OR

```
recyclerView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks, I got my solution by using adapterData.notifyDataSetChanged(); only

Comment: @Kunal can you please post your solution here?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the `onBindViewHolder()` method of every view is called. So you could add something like this in the `onBindViewHolder()` of your `Adapter` method:

```
@Override   
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
            if (refreshedAdapterData.get(position).isInDefaultState()) {
                //set Default View Values
            } else {
                //the code you already have
            }

        }
```

Comment: I have resolved the issue with reference to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Sbruce If this was the answer which helped you the solve your problem it would be fair to mark it as answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this by putting a conditional statement inside onBindViewHolder method instructing all positions to reset the disabled views if data meets the required conditions for a refreshed data.

@Christoph Mayr, thanks for your comments. It helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the data then notify change but the selected checkbox doesn't reset but just moves up one position. Let say I selected item #1 , move out of the RecyclerView, came back and it will auto select item #0.

So, I created new adapter again at onResume(), i worked for me but i don't know if it's the right way to handle this situation.

```html
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(selectedItems != null && selectedItems.size() > 0){
            selectedItems.clear(); // if no selected items before then no need to reset anything
            if(adapter != null && recyclerView != null){
                // to remove the checked box
                adapter = null;
                adapter = new MyAdapter(items, new MyAdapter.MyAdapterListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelected(int pos) {
                        selectedItems.add(items.get(pos));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUnSelected(int pos) {
                        selectedItems.remove(items.get(pos));
                    }
                });
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
    }
```